# Python: use one sqlite query to find the NOT EXISTS result

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, pysqlite

I have a dataset of million entries, its comprised of songs and their artists.

I have

```
a track_id
an artist_id.
```

There are 3 tables

```
tracks (track_id, title, artist_id),
artists(artist_id and artist_name) and
artist_term (artist_id and term).
```

Using only one query, I have to count the number of tracks whose artists don't have any linked terms.

For more reference, the schema of the DB is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE tracks (track_id text PRIMARY KEY, title text, release text, year int, duration real, artist_id text);
CREATE TABLE artists (artist_id text, artist_name text);
CREATE TABLE artist_term (artist_id text, term text, FOREIGN KEY(artist_id) 
REFERENCES artists(artist_id));
```

How do I get to the solution? please help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `not exists`:

```
select count(*) cnt
from tracks t
where not exists (select 1 from artist_term at where at.artist_id = t.artist_id)
```

As far as concerns you do not need to bring in the `artists` table since `artist_id` is available in both `tracks` and `artist_term` tables.

For performance you want an index on `tracks(artist_id)` and another one on `artist_term(artist_id)`.

An anti-`left join` would also get the job done:

```
select count(*) cnt
from tracks t
left join artist_term at on at.artist_id = t.artist_id
where at.artist_id is null
```

Answer (score 0):

You can join the tables `tracks` and `artists` and left join the table `artist_term` so to find the unmatched `artist_id`s:

```
select count(distinct t.track_id)
from tracks t
inner join artists a on a.artist_id = t.artist_id
left join artist_term at on at.artist_id = a.artist_id
where at.artist_id is null
```

The condition `at.artist_id is null` in the `WHERE` clause will return only the unmatched rows which will be counted.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, such a query could be built in a similar fashion like its sibling SQL languages. If so, it should look something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(track_id)
FROM tracks as t
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM artists AS a
    WHERE a.artist_id = t.artist_id
    AND NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT *
        FROM artist_term as at
        WHERE at.artist_id = a.artist_id
    )
)
```

So this query basically says: count the number of different tracks (marked by their unique `track_id`), where there is an artist that has the same `artist_id`, where no `artist_term` exists that refers to the `artist_id` of the artist.

Hope this helps!